# Pushing a 32 bit register onto a '16 bit stack'

Tags: assembly, nasm

This is kind of like three questions in one, anyways here it goes:

1- So I've been searching here on SO for answers to my problem and someone quoted this from somewhere:

> The address-size attribute of the stack segment determines the stack
>   pointer size (16, 32 or 64 bits). The operand-size attribute of the
>   current code segment determines the amount the stack pointer is
>   decremented (2, 4 or 8 bytes).

Can someone explain this to me in a way an assembler newbie like me could understand?

2- The problem is I've created this small stack:

```
setStack:                  ; setup a small stack at 0x9B000

  cli                      ; disable interrupts
  mov AX, 0x9000
  mov SS, AX
  mov SP, 0xB000
  sti                      ; re-enable interrupts
```

Due my (most certain lack of) understanding of the quote at 1 I've assumed that this stack has a 16 bit pointer and the push/pop instructions decrement/increment 2 bytes when they're called? Have I assumed correctly?

3- Supposing I've assumed correctly (i.e: even if I didn't, answer this next question as if I did) what would the next statement perform on the stack?

```
push ECX                   ; ECX is a 32 bit register
```

Thanks in advance kind inhabitants of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stack segment is set up with a 16-bit stack then push/pop will reference SP, and the stack should be aligned on a two byte boundary. Pushing a 16-bit register will occupy one slot, and pushing a 32-bit register will occupy two slots. You can verify this to yourself with the following code:

```
push eax
pop ax
pop bx
```

If the stack segment is set up with a 32-bit stack then push/pop will reference ESP, and the stack should be aligned on a four byte boundary. Pushing a 32-bit register will occupy one slot. Pushing a 16-bit register will cause the stack to become misaligned. This is a bad thing.

The following URL is a copy of the spec for the push instruction from the Intel manual. I've attached the state machine for the push instruction.

http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc266.htm

```
IF StackAddrSize  32
THEN

IF OperandSize  32
THEN
ESP  ESP - 4;
SS:ESP  SRC; (* push doubleword *)
ELSE (* OperandSize  16*)
ESP  ESP - 2;
SS:ESP  SRC; (* push word *)
FI;

ELSE (* StackAddrSize  16*)

IF OperandSize  16
THEN
SP  SP - 2;
SS:SP  SRC; (* push word *)
ELSE (* OperandSize  32*)
SP  SP - 4;
SS:SP  SRC; (* push doubleword *)
FI;

FI;
```

Comment: "because there is no such register in 16-bit mode." 
I don't think this is correct.
You are able to use 32 bit registers in real mode as long as you have a 32 bit capable CPU. You simply can't address 32 bit long addresses.

Comment: You're correct, I'm mistaken. I was too quick to get my modes confused. Let me update my answer will something sensible (and cited).

Answer (score 0):

Try it! (looks like you're in "your own OS", but probably have dos available?)

```
; nasm -f bin -o test32.com test32.asm
bits 16
org 100h

mov eax, 11112222h
push eax
pop ax
pop dx
call ax2hex
mov ax, dx
call ax2hex
ret

;-------------------
ax2hex:
    push cx
    push dx

    mov cx, 4           ; four digits to show

.top
    rol ax, 4           ; rotate one digit into position
    mov dl, al          ; make a copy to process
    and dl, 0Fh         ; mask off a single (hex) digit
    cmp dl, 9           ; is it in the 'A' to 'F' range?
    jbe .dec_dig        ; no, skip it
    add dl, 7           ; adjust
.dec_dig:
    add dl, 30h         ; convert to character

    push ax
    mov ah, 2           ; print the character
    int 21h
    pop ax

    loop .top

    pop dx
    pop cx
    ret
;--------------------------
```

The only opinion that counts is the CPU's opinion!

Best,
Frank